# Check a plugin exists within a Jenkins Pipeline (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use the Slack Notification Plugin in my pipelines, which is very easy:

```
slackSend color: 'danger', message: 'Everything broke'
```

However, I don't want the build to break if slackSend doesn't exist. Is there a way to check that first?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to wrap it in a conditional, though I'm not sure how Jenkins adds stuff to the scripts...

```
if(this.respondsTo('slackSend')) {
    slackSend color: 'danger', message: 'Everything broke'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Jenkins doesn't like it `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods respondsTo java.lang.Object java.lang.String`. I'm seeing this kind of "scripts not permitted to" with a lot of stuff other people seem to be able to use, including `currentBuild.rawBuild` that other people use so I don't know if my pipelines are configured correctly.

Comment: I wonder if it is really the `this` object that you should check for that `respondsTo` on

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the old try/catch to make sure your build doesn't fail on this step :

```
def resultBefore = currentBuild.result
try {
   slackSend color: 'danger', message: 'Everything broke'
} catch(err) {
   currentBuild.result = resultBefore
}
```

However, I don't really see why `slackSend` command would not exist ? It can fail (e.g. if your Slack server is down) but as long as you have `Slack Notification Plugin` installed it should exist !

Comment: It's more about portability. It's on the Jenkins machine I set up myself, but if it gets moved to the main engineering one, I don't want them to have to worry if it's there or not (they have their own thing going on). I tried this approach but it doesn't seem to work. Also, if I'm reporting on a broken build, I wouldn't want to change the build status. :)

Comment: I tried recording the build result before using a function I knew didn't exist and then setting it back in the catch. Unfortunately this still doesn't work `No such DSL method 'thisFunctionNoExists' found among steps`.

Comment: Just tested above code in a simple pipeline and it works perfectly ! You're right, you need to set back previous build result, I edited my post accordingly