# How to test whether a Jenkins Plugin is installed in Pipeline DSL (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have pre-flight checks for my Jenkins pipeline that test whether a certain plugin is installed or not. I found this post [Check a plugin exists within a Jenkins Pipeline (Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100232/check-a-plugin-exists-within-a-jenkins-pipeline-groovy) which asks the same question, but the answers provided are not usable for me, since they test whether a DSL method provided by the plugin is available and not, whether the plugin in general is available or not.

What I would like to have is something like this (in my `Jenkinsfile`):

```
pluginAvailable('plugin-name', '0.0.1')
```

where `0.0.1` might be a (optional) minimum version.

Is there anything like that in the Pipeline DSL or another Jenkins class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the 2nd answer here - [How to get a list of installed jenkins plugins with name and version pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair)

> 2. create a groovy script for parsing (thanks to malenkiy_scot)
>      Save the following as plugins.groovy:
>
> `def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()`
>   `plugins.each {println "${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}"}`

Create a function that accepts a plugin name and version, and iterates over the generated file by the snippet above.

Comment: Putting this in my **Jenkinsfile** caused a failure with `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance`

Comment: @vossad01- you can approve that script from Manage Jenkins. There should be an option there for script approval.

Comment: works fine for me - sorry for not getting back on you in such a long time... but today I needed it and... TADAAA - it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

Had this same thought for a while and put together a helper, just cleaned it up and published an example implementation to github.

```
@Library('shared-utilities@development') _

pluginDependencies = [
  'pipeline-utility-steps': '',       // installed at any version
  'scm-api': '2.6.3',                 // installed and at version 2.6.3
  'build-timestamp':'^1.0.3',         // installed and at version 1.*
  'warnings':'~5.0.0',                // installed and at version 5.0.*
  'config-file-provider': '>3.6.1',   // installed and greater than 3.6.1
  'pipeline-utility-steps': '>=2.3.0',// installed and greater than or eq
  'workflow-basic-steps': '<2.20',    // installed and less than 2.20
  'maven-plugin': '<=3.4'             // installed and less than or eq 3.4
  ]

assertPluginsInstalled( requiredPlugins: pluginDependencies )

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage( 'one' ){
            steps{
                sh "echo 'Running stage after making sure required plugins are installed'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

README for the function
https://github.com/Perficient-DevOps/jenkins-shared-library/blob/master/vars/assertPluginsInstalled.md

Source
https://github.com/Perficient-DevOps/jenkins-shared-library/blob/master/vars/assertPluginsInstalled.groovy